# Segmentation fault when calling a C function from Fortran repeatedly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gfortran

I have a Fortran 90 program which repeatedly calls on a C function. The first time the function is used all goes well, but the second time the code tries to access the function it gives the following error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

I am using gfortran v.4.6 on windows, linking to a library to which I have no source code. The library came to me as a DLL and I used gendef and dlltool to create an .a library to link to.

The code looks like:

```
PROGRAM cmod
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
  INTERFACE
    LOGICAL (C_BOOL) FUNCTION clover(scen,reg,soil,top,rain,depth,numd,nums,numb, numd,addn,srate,stype,nloss,ploss,ErrStr) BIND (C, name = "ClOvr")

    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    INTEGER (C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: scen,reg,soil,topo,depth

    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: rain,numd,nums,numb,numd

    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: addn,srate
    INTEGER (C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: stype
    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(OUT) :: nloss,ploss
    CHARACTER(C_CHAR), INTENT(OUT) :: ErrStr(*)
    END FUNCTION clover
  END INTERFACE
  .....

  do
  .....
    result = clover(a,b,c, d, e, f, g, h, sb, sd, an, sr, st,lossx,lossy,err)
  ......
    result = clover(a,b,c, d, e, f, g, h, sb, sd, an, sr, st,lossx,lossy,err)
  end do
END PROGRAM cmod
```

I don't have the C code, but I am porting from IBM Fortran.

The interface declaration contains these two lines

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES  VALUE :: scen,reg,soil,top,rain,depth,numd,nums,numb,numd,addn,srate,stype

!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES  REFERENCE :: lossx,lossy,ErrStr
```

The IBM fortran uses the following code to load the library and access the function:

```
pointer (q,clover)
p = loadlibrary("clover.dll")
q = getprocaddress(p, "ClOvr")
```

So I might be missing something in the translation to GNU fortran

Comment: The C function must have crashed. But you provide no information which would help understand why.

Comment: providing the C function will help. check the code around out variables, you may find the bug/fix there.

Comment: How are you getting a SIGSEGV on Windows?  Did you get a core dump?

Comment: @cdarke, surprisingly `SIGSEGV` is supported by Windows CRT library, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), although in the oldest documentation version available (VS .NET 2003) it is written that `SIGSEGV` is for compatibility only but still can be generated by `raise()`.

Comment: @Hristo lliev: amazing, I would have expected good ol' 0xC0000005 exception.  I was assuming it was Linux running on a VM, good job I didn't suggest strace. ;-)

Comment: @cdrake, I'm as shocked as you are :) I even tested it with a simple program that dereferences an uninitialised pointer in Release mode - looks like the CRT is translating `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` to `SIGSEGV` if a signal handler is installed.

Comment: [mixing C++ and FORTRAN](http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/comp/docs/notes/not017.html) contains some info on call C++ from FORTRAN and how to specify the calling convention for arguments.  also [calling C from FORTRAN](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/c-with-fortran.html).

Comment: @cdarke I am working in cygwin and there is no core dump.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem: when I compile, I have to use the `-mrtd (sdtcall)`