# Segmentation fault when calling a Delphi function from Fortran

Tags: delphi, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, gfortran

I have a Fortran 90 program which repeatedly calls on a Delphi function. The function gets called a large number of times but eventually the program quits with a segmentation fault.

I have an executable of the code compiled with IBM fortran which works just fine, and I have to recompile the whole thing using gfortran

I have the source code of the main program, but not of the function, which lives in a DLL supplied with the code, and a boreland DLL which presumably supports the Delphi bits: borlndmm.dll

The DLL is 32 bit and I am working on a windows 7 sytem, with a 32bit gfortran compiler with specs:

```
COLLECT_GCC=C:\program files (x86)\gcc\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program files (x86)/gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2-mingw/configure --host=i686-pc-mingw32 --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=i686-pc-mi    ngw32 --prefix=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_32/gcc/4.7.2 --with-gcc --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --wi    th-cloog=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_32/cloog --with-gmp=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/nat    ive/x86_32/gmp --with-mpfr=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_32/mpfr --with-mpc=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/b    inary/mingw32/native/x86_32/mpc --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --with-sysroot=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/cross/x8    6_32/gcc/4.7.2 --disable-shared --disable-nls --disable-tls --disable-win32-registry --enable-libquadmath-support --enabl    e-libquadmath --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-threads=win32 --enable-lto --enable-static --ena    ble-shared=lto-plugin --enable-plugins --with-host-libstdcxx='-lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm' --with-ppl=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/b    inary/mingw32/native/x86_32/ppl --enable-ld=yes
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)
```

I've previously posted a question about this code (see [Segmentation fault when calling a C function from Fortran repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131453)) but that was only the first stumbling block.

I compile the code with

```
>> gfortran -o cmod cmod.f90  -fbounds-check -ffree-line-length-none -dH -mrtd -g -L. Clues.dll
```

But I can't even get a dump output when it fails. 
I am thinking that I have a problem with memory alignment when calling the Delphi function, which eventually kills me. 
Or I may not be compiling correctly for 32 bit on a 64 bit system, I don't have any experience with this.
Any idea on how to proceed would be most welcome.

The function definition in the original fortran code for IBM fortran is:

```
module overseer
 use kernel32
 interface
   function CluesOvr(scenario,region,soilorder,topography,rainfall,ASoildepth,Snumdairy,Snumsheep,Snumbeef,Snumdeer,AdditionalNitrogen,Supplementrate,SupplementType,Nloss,Ploss,ErrStr)
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES  VALUE :: scenario,region,soilorder,topography,rainfall,ASoildepth,Snumdairy,Snumsheep,Snumbeef,Snumdeer,AdditionalNitrogen,Supplementrate,SupplementType
   !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES  REFERENCE :: Nloss,Ploss,ErrStr
   LOGICAL CluesOvr
   integer*4 scenario,region,soilorder,topography,ASoildepth
   real*8 rainfall,Snumdairy,Snumsheep,Snumbeef,Snumdeer
   real*8 AdditionalNitrogen,Supplementrate
   Integer*4 SupplementType
   real*8 Nloss,Ploss
   character ErrStr(40)
   end function CluesOvr
 end interface
end module
```

which I have translated to:

```
INTERFACE
 LOGICAL (C_BOOL) FUNCTION CluesOvr(scenario,region,soilorder,topography,rainfall, &
    ASoildepth,Snumdairy,Snumsheep,Snumbeef,Snumdeer,AdditionalNitrogen, &
    Supplementrate, SupplementType,Nloss,Ploss, &
    ErrStr) BIND (C, name='CluesOvr')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER (C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: scenario,region,soilorder,topography,ASoildepth
    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: rainfall,Snumdairy,Snumsheep,Snumbeef,Snumdeer
    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: AdditionalNitrogen,Supplementrate
    INTEGER (C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: SupplementType
    REAL (C_DOUBLE), INTENT(OUT) :: Nloss,Ploss
    CHARACTER(C_CHAR), INTENT(OUT) :: ErrStr(*)
  END FUNCTION CluesOvr
END INTERFACE
```

The IBM code also uses

```
 pointer (q,CluesOvr)
 p = loadlibrary("CluesOvr.dll")
 q = getprocaddress(p, "CluesOvr")
```

to access the function.  I don't do that with gfortran.

Comment: We cannot help if we don't know what the interface contract is. What is the Pascal declaration of the function? Or do you have a C or C++ header file for it? And what is your Fortran code? If you want us to help, you'll need to supply both sides of the interop interface.

Comment: Don't attempt to ask the question in comments. Ask it in the question. Make an edit.

Comment: No I don't have the Delphi code, just the fortran side of the code and a DLL (also comes with a boreland DLL which I assume has something to do with the delphi code)

Comment: If you have no specification of the other side of the interface, how do you know how to call it? And how can we possibly help? It's time for you to abandon a DLL that comes with no documentation and use libraries that are properly documented. It's a waste of everybody's time by asking us to reason about something that has absolutely no specification whatsoever. That is simply put, not what programming is about.

Comment: Because the I have the source of fortran code that calls the function. Only the compiler is different (and possibly the OS)

Comment: It's legacy code, that's what I stuck with

Comment: And again with the imprecision. "It comes with a boreland DLL". The DLL has got a name. You could tell us what that name is exactly. And stop us having to guess. There's  no fun in guessing. So, what is the name of that DLL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too localized". This is too specific to your situation to be of any use to others in the future. I don't think we can help with this question. (There's also no Delphi information available, according to you, so it's probably inappropriate for the Delphi tag.)

Comment: Added to the main question section for documentation.

Comment: OK, fair enough, can you recommend a source of information on how to properly compile 32 bit code on a 64 bit windows machine? Thanx

Comment: @GabriellaTurek: There is no need for a source of that information. Compiling 32-bit code on a 64-bit machine is the same as compiling 32-bit code on a 32-bit machine - it depends entirely on the compiler you're using. That's also not the question you asked here (and if it were, I'd vote to close it as "not a real question").

Comment: It would be useful to know what this DLL is and why you are using a DLL that has no documentation. What app is the DLL supposed to be used by? It's not meant for general purpose consumption is it?

Answer (score 3):

The presence of `borlandmm.dll` suggests that your task is close to impossible. That DLL is used to allow different modules (e.g. an executable and a DLL) to share a common Delphi memory manager. This allows for one module, the executable say, to allocate a Delphi string, and pass it to the other module, the DLL say, which in turn can deallocate the string.

Unless both modules share the same heap, such an architecture cannot work. The `borlandmm.dll` library makes heap sharing across modules possible. Any DLL that wishes to use the Delphi memory manager of its host includes the `Sharemem` unit which in turn uses the `borlandmm.dll` library to effect memory manager sharing.

Now, your Fortran host cannot possibly meet the required contract. The only thing that can provide a Delphi memory manager is a Delphi host. What will be happening is that the DLL you call believes that it is responsible for freeing the memory that it is passed. The DLL probably receives Delphi `string` variables which are heap allocated. When the DLL attempts to free memory, that memory was allocated in your Fortran host process. And that mismatch is likely what is leading to access violations. These will not necessarily occur every time you call the function.

The design of this DLL, to use `borlandmm.dll` is reasonable provided that it was expected only to be called from a Delphi host. If the developer of the DLL knew what they were doing then they would have been aware of that restriction. The fact that you have got no documentation for the DLL suggests to me that you've extracted the DLL from another program and are trying to use it in a way in which it was not designed. Your chances of success are exceptionally low.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I may be able to get to the source of the code at another institution altogether and see where I can get with that. Dealing with scientists, not necessarily the best code writers. I have to cope as best as I can.